# It kept saying java.lang.nullpointerxception. Being trying to figure out what is is. Help Anyone?

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception

Been trying to figure out what is wrong with the code. Is there anything that i'm not doing it right ?

public class deck2 {
    public Card[] deck;

```
public void CreateDeck() {
    String[] suit = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };//Array for suit
    int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }; // Array for rank

    for (int i = 0; i <suit.length ; i++) {//Looping the suit array
        for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) { // Looping the number array
            Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[i]); //Calling the constructor from my card class
            if (deck[i] == null) {
                deck[i] = c;


            }

        }

    }

}

public void displayDeck() {
    for (int i = 0; i <deck.length; i++) {
        if (deck[i] != null) {
            deck[i].display(); // Calling the display method from my card class. 
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did you debug? What happens? Where?

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what line it happens on. Which line is it? And what happens when you set a breakpoint there in the debugger and step through the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll guess that your deck is null.

```
public class deck2 { 

public Card[] deck;  // deck is null

public deck2() {
   deck = new Card[52]; // now it's not.
}

public void CreateDeck() {
    String[] suit = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };//Array for suit
    int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }; // Array for rank

    for (int i = 0; i <suit.length ; i++) {//Looping the suit array
        for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) { // Looping the number array
            Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[i]); //Calling the constructor from my card class
            if (deck[i] == null) {
                deck[i] = c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is still bad.  You'll end up with only 13 cards, not 52: all clubs.  (Do you see why?)